# How to get XMLHTTPRequest object on server side in asp.net c#

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, html

i want to send the json data from client side(javascript) to server side(ASP.NET,C#) using HTML5. i am using XMLHttpRequest Object to send data to the server by using the following javascript code. i am executing this code behind the html button click.

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var jsonString = JSON.stringify(jsonObj);
xhr.open('GET', '/HTML5_Crud.aspx?obj='+jsonString, true);
xhr.send();
```

on server side (ASPX.cs) file i am using the following code in Page_Load method to get data from client.

```
if (Request.QueryString["obj"] != null)
{
    jsonStr= Convert.ToString(Request.QueryString["obj"]);
    lblTest.Text = "the json is: "+ jsonStr;
}
```

but when i run the application and clicks the button my label is not updated with the latest data. it still the same as default text i set inline. please help me how can i resolve this issue.

Comment: try adding a callback function in your ajax request.. if you familiar with it

Answer (score 0):

In the second code snippet, the value of lblTest.Text only exists within the context of the request you made from javascript. There is no magic way to update the response originally sent to the browser. If you want that to be update you have to do either:

1. Use a postback instead of javascript and update the page
2. Use javascript to read the response from the Ajax request and then update the DOM client side.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to do two different things. the XMLHttpRequest is used for an AJAX request, and what you are doing in the back-end will only update your page when it is reloaded. But because you are sending an AJAX request, the page is never refreshed.

What you need to be doing is respond in your code-behind with a string or something, and in your javascript, use the string as appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Your label will not update this way.

Instead you should return the value to your request and handle it xhr's `onreadystatechange` event.

Or you can wrap the label in an UpdatePanel and add a button that will store the value in a hidden field for example and cause a postback. Then you could retrieve the value from this field and the whole panel would update to the new values.